# Assumptions about energy for a spontaneous process?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

For a "spontaneous" process, i.e., $\Delta G<0$. Are there any assumptions that can be made for the change in internal energy $\Delta E$ ?

At a basic level, $\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S = \Delta E + \Delta (PV) - T \Delta S$.

I am simply wondering, knowing nothing else about a transition, if there is anything else that can be inferred.

Comment: That should be $\Delta G^0$, not $\Delta G$,  And, it is only a rule of thumb.  Do you know how $\Delta G^0$ is defined, specifically in terms of the initial and final states implied?

Comment: Hi Chet, nice to hear from you again. I may be looking at the wrong books, they seem loose with the notation. So the standard state free energy change is equal to the change in total internal energy plus the other terms shown? Also, the standard state free energy change would be 1 M or 1 atm for initial and final states; beyond this is there something I am missing that you are referring to?

Comment: This is rather prolonged development.  Step 1.  For an ideal gas reaction, please state your understanding of the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states that define $\Delta G^0$, the standard change in Gibbs free energy.